Node js profiling (--prof) provides a high percentage of unaccounted
I'm trying to profile my application using built in profiler, but the vast majority of ticks during execution are labelled as unaccounted. I'll report here the processed log. I've seen similar questions here on stack overflow, and I've tried to follow their advises, but the result is still the same (updating node, using different parameters to lower the tick period, using non optimized execution...). I've read also about some differences between node and d8 shell but I haven't understood much. Also other similar questions are old, maybe some new options are available or the problem changed. To make it more clear:

Windows 11
Using node 22.5.1
Used node --prof prova.js and node --prof-process isolate-0x28a76f7d000-13900-v8.log > processedLog.txt
I'm using node installed via minGW64 and Msys2

here's the very simple code (prova.js) I've profiled:
console.log('menz')
let a = []
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) a.push(i)
console.log(a)

This is the processed log:
Statistical profiling result from isolate-0x28a76f7d000-13900-v8.log, (19 ticks, 18 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      1    5.3%    5.3%  Builtin: Call_ReceiverIsNotNullOrUndefined

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      1    5.3%    5.3%  JavaScript
      0    0.0%    0.0%  C++
      0    0.0%    0.0%  GC
      0    0.0%          Shared libraries
     18   94.7%          Unaccounted

 [C++ entry points]:
   ticks    cpp   total   name

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
     18   94.7%  UNKNOWN
      7   38.9%    JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      7  100.0%      JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1   14.3%        JS: ~getTranslators node:internal/modules/esm/loader:74:24
      1  100.0%          JS: ~ModuleLoader node:internal/modules/esm/loader:108:20
      1  100.0%            JS: ~ModuleLoader node:internal/modules/esm/loader:147:14
      1   14.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:tty:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1   14.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/webstreams/util:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1   14.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/url:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ~compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ~requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1   14.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/streams/duplex:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1   14.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/fs/promises:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1   14.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/blob:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      3   16.7%    JS: ~compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      3  100.0%      JS: ~requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      2   66.7%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/bootstrap/node:1:1
      1   33.3%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/timers:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ~compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ~requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1    5.6%    JS: ~setupDebugEnv node:internal/process/pre_execution:455:23
      1  100.0%      JS: ~prepareExecution node:internal/process/pre_execution:99:26
      1  100.0%        JS: ~prepareMainThreadExecution node:internal/process/pre_execution:55:36
      1  100.0%          JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/main/run_main_module:1:1
      1    5.6%    JS: ~makeNodeErrorWithCode node:internal/errors:428:31
      1  100.0%      JS: ~E node:internal/errors:549:11
      1  100.0%        JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/errors:1:1
      1  100.0%          JS: ~compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%            JS: ~requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1    5.6%    JS: ~afterWriteDispatched node:internal/stream_base_commons:156:30
      1  100.0%      JS: ~writeGeneric node:internal/stream_base_commons:148:22
      1  100.0%        JS: ~Socket._writeGeneric node:net:921:42
      1  100.0%          JS: ~Socket._write node:net:963:35
      1  100.0%            JS: ~writeOrBuffer node:internal/streams/writable:546:23
      1    5.6%    JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/net:1:1
      1  100.0%      JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27
      1  100.0%        JS: ^requireBuiltin node:internal/bootstrap/realm:421:24
      1  100.0%          JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/dns/utils:1:1
      1  100.0%            JS: ^compileForInternalLoader node:internal/bootstrap/realm:384:27

      1    5.3%  Builtin: Call_ReceiverIsNotNullOrUndefined
      1  100.0%    JS: ^copyPrototype node:internal/per_context/primordials:121:23
      1  100.0%      JS: ^<anonymous> node:internal/per_context/primordials:224:11
      1  100.0%        Builtin: ArrayForEach
      1  100.0%          JS: ~<anonymous> node:internal/per_context/primordials:1:1

